# Forwarding constructor arguments in call-by-value (c++)

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a function like this

```
    void foo(std::vector<int> data)
```

Now I would like to call this function, but the vector I have is quite large and I need to pass only a certain part of it. Obviously I would like to avoid unnecessary copies (the function `foo` is supposed to make one local copy of the vector with that it's called though).

I would like to achieve something like this:

```
    std::vector<int> largeVector(1e6); // some large data vector
    int nPointsToUse = 400; // only a small fraction of it is needed
    int offset = 2000;
    foo(largeVector.begin() + offset, largeVector.begin() + offset + nPointsToUse)
```

But that obviously doesn't work, since `foo` expects one argument which is a vector of ints.

I could just make a copy of only the slice of the data vector before calling `foo` and then pass the copied vector by reference to the function but I would like to leave its signature unchanged.

Is there a nice way to achieve what I want? So that the function basically calls the constructor of the vector with the arguments I am providing to the function?

Comment: you could pass iterators instead of the vector

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) should apply:

```
foo({largeVector.begin() + offset, largeVector.begin() + offset + nPointsToUse});
```

Else change `foo` to take iterator or range (as [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span)).

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank's a lot. I am still learning c++ and this is the first time I hear about copy elision, very nice :)

Comment: I don't think you're using copy elision here.  It looks like it is either direct or copy initialization of the parameter: *When a function is called, each parameter ([dcl.fct]) is initialized ([dcl.init], [class.copy.ctor]) with its corresponding argument.* https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.call#7

Answer (score 0):

You cannot avoid at least one copy of the `vector` with the current version of `foo`

If you own the `foo` function and its doing a read only operation on the `vector` change the signature to `void foo(const vector<int> & x)`

If you can't change the signature then you can use `std::move` at the caller end to avoid an extra unnecessary copy.

```
foo(std::move(newVectorSlice))
```

Comment: You can construct in-place, so no copy.

Comment: Op says he/she already has a big vector. They want to pass a slice of it.

Comment: Yes, but I need this one copy of the slice of the vector, since `foo` does change the vector it gets passed (and I don't wan't my original vector to be changed). I hope that I am really just doing one copy when I call the function as Jarod42 suggested